# How to get the progress of geth node syncing info via JSON RPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I install new geth nodes on remote servers pretty often and I'd like to have a script which can tell me info like this: Node1 is synced for 30%.

Is it possible to get any progress of geth node syncing info via JSON RPC?

Accuracy is not very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [eth_syncing](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_syncing) to determine that status of your sync.